# Is it possible to control in velocity the DJI M210 drone throught the UART port with NVIDIA Jetson TX2?

Tags: ros, dji-sdk, nvidia-jetson, px4

I would like to use a DJI M210 drone for mapping. I'm actually using a LiDAR and the SLAM algorithm to map a GPS-denied environment. I would like to know, if someone knows, is it possible to control the drone in velocity, without the GPS (I would send Odometry to the drone from SLAM). I've read that the velocity control from DJI is only done by the GPS interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to control the method using only local coordinate system. I tested with various SLAM on various DJI drone/FCU with all kind of PC TK1 TX2 UPsqare NUC Manifold1 and 2(both cpu and gpu). Only problem is that you cant use the GPS mission way.

Use raw command way. remove all GPS related

```
sensor_msgs::Joy controlVelYawRate;
uint8_t flag = (DJISDK::VERTICAL_VELOCITY   |
            DJISDK::HORIZONTAL_VELOCITY |
            DJISDK::YAW_RATE            |
            DJISDK::HORIZONTAL_GROUND   |
            DJISDK::STABLE_ENABLE);
controlVelYawRate.axes.push_back(y);
controlVelYawRate.axes.push_back(p);
controlVelYawRate.axes.push_back(r);
controlVelYawRate.axes.push_back(t);
controlVelYawRate.axes.push_back(flag);

ctrlBrakePub.publish(controlVelYawRate);
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. Just to clarify with you, are you able to send the Odometry data to the drone so it can use is own control loop or you are using your onboard computer to make the SLAM and a control loop, so you can send velocity command to the drone?

Comment: yes I can. see my video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AbfRENy3OQ&t=90s . on onboard PC. the control node subscribe from state esimation feedback and use to control the drone according to the path planning output. The fused control output is send to the drone for action